# Source of project errors in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

Very often, it is the case that there is a compilation error in a project, yet I can't really find the source of the error.

For instance:

[image]

This web project has an error, yet it's basically my guess as to what the error is. Why isn't there a way to right-click an option called "find source of compilation error"? There's no quick fix option available.

This is a simple question. I don't understand why this is an issue, because Eclipse knows what the problem is, but why won't Eclipse tell me?

Comment: There should be a "Problems" view that you can open up that lists all errors and warnings in all open projects.

Comment: I don't want to answer as a question as it's probably a duplicate, but here's the solution: `Window -> Show View -> Problems`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> then type `Problems` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This should show a list of all the issues in the project.

[image]